# Как считается репутация за ответы?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Обнаружил пару необычных мест с подсчётом репутации и стало интересно, почему так?

> 245 16 сен
>   [Как добавить содержимое регистра bl и bh в регистр ax в ассемблере?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451378/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-bl-%D0%B8-bh-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80-ax-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5/451383#451383)
>
> ```
> +12 / -2   17:22   5 событий 
>  +2   17:22   голос за   
>  -2   16:50   голос против
>       16:48   голос за   
>       16:48   голос за   
> +10   16:30   голос за
> ```

> 215 сегодня [Старший бит числа 0 в двоичном представлении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453066/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/453067#453067)
>
> ```
> +45   12 минут назад   5 событий
>  +5   12 минут назад   голос за  
> +10   1 час назад      голос за  
> +10   2 часа назад     голос за  
> +10   2 часа назад     голос за  
> +10   2 часа назад     голос за
> ```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Вы достигли daily reputation cap, поздравляю!

По правилам, участник сайта не может заработать более 200 баллов голосами за его ответы. Если у вас на момент последнего голоса «за» было 198 баллов, этот голос добавит только 2 балла.

При этом баллы за *принятые* ответы (+15) не включаются в подсчёт. Зато они включаются в подсчёт количества дней, в течение которых вы набирали +200 баллов. (Это приносит беджи «Эпопея» и «Легенда».)

Comment: Также не включаются в подсчёт, очки репутации, приобретённые на bounty.