# Голоса за авторский ответ без зачисления баллов

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если ответ помечен общим, то за него баллы не начисляются, если ответ авторский, за каждый голос зачисляется 10 баллов, даже если набрал потолок в 200 баллов за день.

Не могу понять что с [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541078)? Картина начисления баллов выглядит очень странно

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d65zueae7

Есть этому какое-то объяснение? Где сбой? В начислении баллов или в отображении голосов за ответы? Или здесь какой-то третий вариант?

Comment: набрать больше 200 баллов в день можно **только** за счет бонусов и принятых ответов

Comment: вероятно, вы превысили лимит в 200 баллов репутации за день: [В день можно заработать до 200 баллов репутации любым сочетанием приведенных ниже действий. Конкурсы, принятые ответы и бонусы за подключения к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов не ограничены дневным пределом репутации.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Ага, только за принятые ответы? Мне кажется или система работает с задержкой? Три последних раза, когда я превышаю 200 баллов репутации, она доходила до 260 (иногда до 290) и в интервал от 200 до 260 входят баллы в том числе за непринятые ответы - обычные голоса за ответы (в вопросах где автора уже нет и принять ответ некому)? Или я не учитываю какой-то фактор?

Comment: имелось ввиду: если уже есть 200 баллов в день, то за принятие ответа будет добавлено 15, а за просто плюс - нет

Comment: @Grundy, я понял, но 100% зачислялись голоса за плюсы уже после 200 баллов. Сегодня я как раз был у компьютера, когда был преодолены 200 баллов и почти сразу были обычные голоса, я бы 60 по 15 не набрал бы, у меня всего сегодня 4 принятых ответа за весь день, а они были приняты до того, как был достигнут порог в 200 баллов.

Comment: Или 15 * 4 = 60 и есть эти лишние 60 баллов сверх 200?

Comment: ага, это именно они

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь понятно.

Comment: близко по тематике: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1377/178576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сколько бы «плюсов» ни поставили за ваши вопросы (по 5 баллов репутации за каждый «плюс») и ответы (по 10 баллов репутации за каждый «плюс») **в течение дня** (по гринвичу), вам будет начислено **за них** не более 200 баллов репутации.

баллы же за принятые ответы (по 15 баллов за каждый), баллы [за подключение учётных записей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2886/178576) (по 100 баллов на каждом сайте) и баллы, полученные за конкурсы, в этом ограничении вообще «не участвуют».

---

если вы, например, получили за день 100 «плюсов» за ответы, и пять ответов было принято авторами вопросов, то ваша репутация за этот день увеличится не на 1075 баллов (100*10+5*15), а только на 275 (200+5*15).

что должно утешить — вы станете на один шаг ближе к обретению знаков:

- [«академик»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard) (бронза, вручается за первый факт набора 200 баллов/день)
- [«эпопея»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic) (серебро, за 50 раз)
- [«легенда»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary) (золото, за 150 раз)

да и все остальные знаки, касающиеся полученных вами «плюсов», будут присуждаться исправно, вне зависимости от того, начислены вам за какой-то конкретный «плюс» баллы репутации, или не начислены.

---

близкий по тематике вопрос: [Как считается репутация за ответы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1377/178576)